# Rails, where to store JSON credentials of Google Client API and how to access it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

In my Google Developer Console, I have downloaded credentials json file. It looks like this:

```
client_secret-000000000-aaaaaaaaaa0a.apps.googleusercontent.json
```

I want to use `google-api-client` for ruby. In what folder do I need to place this `json` file? Also, how can I access it? All tutorials about this just skips it.

Answer (score 2):

You may store it in any suitable directory, e. g. `config` (conventionally), `lib`, `db` etc.

To access it, use:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(
  application_name: 'Your Google API Application',
  application_version: YOUR_VERSION
)
client.authorization = 
Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(
  File.join(
    Rails.root,
    'config',
    'client_secret-000000000-aaaaaaaaaa0a.apps.googleusercontent.json'
  )
).to_authorization
```

Comment: Their documentation just calls the `.load` method directly. Any idea where it attempts to load from by default (so we don't have to specify a path like this)
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#preparing-to-start-the-oauth-20-flow