# Connecting to Google Calendar's API through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a really simple Rails application with one specific purpose: add a Calendar event to a Google Calendar account.

I'm following the [Ruby Guide from the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/start/get_started).

I was able to run the provided testing code (Ruby only, no framework) but I'm having a hard time accessing the credentials from a Rails project and I'm not sure the proper ("idiomatic"?) way to do it and organize the project.

Part of the process is using OAuth 2.0 since this goal requires access to Google User's private data (both read and write), I'm following the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Services](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/web-app) instructions.

Right now I have several different questions regarding best practices and/or the proper way to organize code:

1. Google provides a *client_secret.json* that have the credentials to access the application. Where should I keep it? Should I keep it in a **.env** file in the Development environment and (in my case) in Heroku's *ENV VARS* in the Production Environment?
2. I tried keeping the *client_secret.json* file in the project's root folder (same path as the *Gemfile*), added it to the *.gitignore* but I wasn't able to `require "#{Rails.root}/client_secret.json"`:

   ```
   /Users/jsoifer/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': No such file to load -- /Users/jsoifer/Developer/Tiny-Things/tiny-booking/client_secret.json (LoadError)
   ```
3. I created a `services/` folder to put the Google Calendar related code inside, I wasn't sure if I should put is in a controller though. How should I organize this?

**Important consideration:**
I'm not using any other method of Authentication/Authorization such as *Devise* or others and I'm not planning to do so right now. I just want to get Google's Authorization token and create a Calendar event.

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/tiny-things/tiny-booking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and will post the answer to each of the questions below:

1. [One of the possible locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372312/rails-where-to-store-json-credentials-of-google-client-api-and-how-to-access-it) for the *client_secret.json* file is `config/client_secret.json`.
   When shipping to Production in Heroku, use ENV Vars.
2. Require is not the appropriate way to import the credentials in the json file.
   Use `Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load( File.join( Rails.root, 'config', 'client_secret.json' ) )` (assuming the file is indeed in `config/`.
3. [There are several different alternatives](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/where-do-you-put-your-code/) as on how to organize code. I ended up creating a services folder and a google_calendar.rb class holding the authorization logic.

**Here's the code:**

`app/services/google_calendar.rb`

```rb
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'

class GoogleCalendar 
  # Attributes Accessors (attr_writer + attr_reader)
  attr_accessor :auth_client, :auth_uri, :code

  def initialize

    # ENV: Development
    # Google's API Credentials are in ~/config/client_secret.json
    client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load( File.join( Rails.root, 'config', 'client_secret.json' ) )
    @auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization

    # Specify privileges and callback URL
    @auth_client.update!(
      :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback'
    )

    # Build up the Redirecting URL
    @auth_uri = @auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s

  end

end
```

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Starting action in config/routes.rb
  def welcome

    # Redirect to Google Authorization Page
    redirect_to GoogleCalendar.new.auth_uri

  end

  def token
    # Get a auth_client object from Google API
    @google_api = GoogleCalendar.new

    @google_api.auth_client.code = params[:code] if params[:code]
    response = @google_api.auth_client.fetch_access_token!

    session[:access_token] = response['access_token']

    # Whichever Controller/Action needed to handle what comes next
    redirect_to new_event_path()
  end

end
```